# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the sub-query is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

```
SELECT
  ( Select 
COUNT(t2.ID) as Total_HH_Memebers_Primary,t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 
from 
PScData t1 
INNER JOIN 
PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   PScData t1
               WHERE  t1.SETTLEMENT_ID = SETTLEMENT_ID 
                AND t2.EDUCATION_LEVEL = 5 
               HAVING Count(*) > 1)
               Group By t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 
) col1



  , (Select 
COUNT(t2.ID) as Total_HH_Memebers_Secondary,t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 
from 
PScData t1 
INNER JOIN 
PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
 WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   PScData t1
               WHERE  t1.SETTLEMENT_ID = SETTLEMENT_ID 
                AND t2.EDUCATION_LEVEL = 10 
              HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
               Group By t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 

) col2
```

Here is my query, i want to get two different results based on "WHERE" condition from same table in the form of columns when i do this its giving this error .can somebody how to it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.EDUCATION_LEVEL = 5
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_HH_Members_Primary,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.EDUCATION_LEVEL = 10
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total_HH_Members_Secondary,
    t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 
FROM PScData t1 
INNER JOIN PscMemberData t2
    ON t2._PARENT_AURI = t1.URI
GROUP BY
    t1.SETTLEMENT_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The two subqueries in the select clause look totally unnecessary to me.  And also I think we can remove the `EXISTS` clause, and move the `HAVING` clause to the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Try With cte

```
;with col1 as 
(  Select 
COUNT(t2.ID) as Total_HH_Memebers_Primary,t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 
from 
PScData t1 
INNER JOIN 
PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   PScData t1
               WHERE  t1.SETTLEMENT_ID = SETTLEMENT_ID 
                AND t2.EDUCATION_LEVEL = 5 
               HAVING Count(*) > 1)
               Group By t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 
),col2 as 
(Select 
COUNT(t2.ID) as Total_HH_Memebers_Secondary,t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 
from 
PScData t1 
INNER JOIN 
PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
 WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   PScData t1
               WHERE  t1.SETTLEMENT_ID = SETTLEMENT_ID 
                AND t2.EDUCATION_LEVEL = 10 
              HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
               Group By t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 

)  

select col1.SETTLEMENT_ID,col2.Total_HH_Memebers_Secondary, col1.Total_HH_Memebers_Primary from col1 
join col2 on col1.SETTLEMENT_ID=col2.SETTLEMENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that: A sub-query in the select list IS NOT ALLOWED TO return more than ONE VALUE, and this is true for EACH subquery.

You have 2 columns AND multiple rows returned from this query:

```
Select COUNT(t2.ID) as Total_HH_Memebers_Primary, t1.SETTLEMENT_ID 
from PScData t1 
INNER JOIN PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   PScData t1
               WHERE  t1.SETTLEMENT_ID = SETTLEMENT_ID 
                AND t2.EDUCATION_LEVEL = 5 
               HAVING Count(*) > 1)
Group By t1.SETTLEMENT_ID
```

**So IT IS NOT ALLOWED as a "subquery" inside a select clause.**

You need to use "conditional aggregates" instead, explained elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted the above answer and i have found another method for it as well:

Both methods are feasible,the method that i have found is given below:

```
WITH EDU_LEVEL AS 
(SELECT t1.SETTLEMENT_ID,t2.EDUCATION_LEVEL from 
PScData t1 
INNER JOIN 
PscMemberData t2 ON t2._PARENT_AURI  = t1.URI
)


SELECT  SETTLEMENT_ID,
(Select COUNT(*) FROM EDU_LEVEL    WHERE  SETTLEMENT_ID = T.SETTLEMENT_ID AND EDUCATION_LEVEL = 5 ) Total_HH_Memebers_Primary,
(Select COUNT(*) FROM EDU_LEVEL    WHERE  SETTLEMENT_ID = T.SETTLEMENT_ID AND EDUCATION_LEVEL = 10 ) Total_HH_Memebers_Secondary



FROM EDU_LEVEL AS T
Group By SETTLEMENT_ID
```